# UITableView (NOT using Navigation Template) or AppDelegate to DetailView

Tags: uitableview, plist, detailsview

I'd like to display a Details view from a select row event on a UITableView sitting on a regular View.  Somehow I imagine I could get the selectedIndex and for the Detail view I can have that value passed in to the View.  I'm just thinking out loud and from the mindset of a web era programmer.  My tableview gets it's data from a plist.  Any code samples out there would be great but I doubt there are any.  I've search for 3 days trying to find one.

Thanks

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
 NSDictionary *rowDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[contacts objectAtIndex:row]];
}

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to open a new NIB and pass the selected index value in.

Comment: I've almost got the open new XIB.  Now I just need to know how to display array items from item # x (selectedIndex) so I can display that detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nearly impossible.  I just surrendered and started with a Navigation Template.  Everything is smooth as silk.